# VBA Copy Formula to Last Row Then Next Column

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working with the code below, and where I'm having a hard time getting this around is the piece in brackets `[CURRENT COLUMN]`

I can't quite seem to get it to use the currently used column to paste the formula down.

The goal is to go from columns `K` to `END` then if there is a formula in row 2 of that column, copy that formula down and proceed to the next column.

```
Option Explicit
Sub recalcdash()
Dim oWkbk As Workbook
Dim oWkst As Worksheet
Dim oRng As Range
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim StartCol As Integer
Dim StartRow As Long


StartCol = 11
Set oWkst = ActiveSheet


LastRow = oWkst.Range("A" & oWkst.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = oWkst.Cells(2, oWkst.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For Each oRng In Range(Cells(2, 11), Cells(2, LastCol))
        If oRng.HasFormula Then
            oRng.Copy
            Range(Cells(2, StartCol), Cells(LastRow, [CURRENT COLUMN])).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormulas)
        End If
        Next oRng

End Sub
```

Comment: `oRng.Column` ...? and you probably want to change the reference to StartCol too?

Comment: Dang I tried that once and something about the `oRng` was returning only a `1 to n`. But yeah I think that worked.

Comment: Note that `Range` and `Cells` calls should be qualified with `oWkst`. Otherwise your code will break when you set `oWkst` to anything other than `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: In this case, the Ranges are being built up from the Cells, so only the Cells should be qualified. The Ranges are quite safe either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to modify

```
Range(Cells(2, StartCol), Cells(LastRow, [CURRENT COLUMN])).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormulas
```

to

```
Range(Cells(2, oRng.Column), Cells(LastRow, oRng.Column)).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormulas)
```